# curl is executed twice from crontab

Tags: linux, unix, centos, php, crontab

I have installed centos 7 and PHP 5.6.29 on my server, and I set up crontab to run this command every 15 minutes:

```
*/15 * * * * curl http://example.com/check.php
```

but the command is run twice. Is there a way to fix this problem?

When I run the command manually from the command line:

```
curl http://example.com/check.php
```

it works, but when it is run via crontab it runs twice.

I checked with `wget` in place of `curl` but the problem is the same.

Comment: Have a look in the log file - might be /var/log/cron, /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog, but you should see what is being executed and when.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have more than one cron daemon running

```
ps -ef | grep crond
```

See [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/228653).